# Play 2.4 Content-Length header with Heroku

Tags: playframework

I have several Play applications in Heroku that I recently migrated to version 2.4. After deploying to Heroku I've noticed that the app does not return Content-Length header. 
Example - curl -v -X GET http://oc-keepalive.herokuapp.com
This application is created using a minimal play-scala application template without any modifications. And the same application returns Content-Length header when running locally.
This may have several implications, one of them is support for "Keep-Alive" connections: Heroku router will set "Connection: close" header regardless of what the original "Connection" header was set to.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku will also keep the connection open if it sees a "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" header. Can you adjust your code to use `Ok.chunked` as described in this doc?
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaStream